# Is it possible to override pass?

Tags: python

Recently I programmed a UI in tkinter and while showing it to colleagues they always seemed to try methods which still contained the keyword `pass`.

As you know this means the method was not implemented yet and *nothing* happened...

To prevent questions about obviously not written code I started adding a little messagebox:

```py
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def example_method():
    showinfo("Not Supported!", "This feature is not implemented yet.\n"
                                                   "It will be added in a later version.")
```

While this **does** work, I started to think about better solutions without reformatting the code too much.
In this process I stumbled about a solution suggesting to just use a (lambda-) function.

Although I went with this solution in the end I just wanted to know if there might be a possibility to override the keyword `pass` to change its behaviour to call my own method. This would need very little reformatting of existing code.

An example to clarify what I mean:

```py
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def __pass__(): # Overrides pass behaviour
    showinfo("Not Supported!", "This feature is not implemented yet.\n"
                                               "It will be added in a later version.")
def unimplemented_method():
    pass
```

*Note: The reason why I ask this maybe dumb sounding question is because Python is a very customizable language which also allows me to override operator-behaviour. I already doubt it but Python surprised me more than once...*

Comment: No. `pass` is a keyword. You can't "override" it without re-writing and re-compiling the interpreter

Comment: FYI, `raise NotImplementedError` is often the more appropriate practice if you want to generate an error (or something you can otherwise catch and provide custom handling for at an outer scope) when use of not-yet-implemented functionality is attempted. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError

Comment: Ok thanks. Especially your solution is one I quite like @Charles Duffy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, so you could maybe put the whole program (or just `main`) in a `try` block and then do `except NotImplementedError: showinfo("Not Supported!", ...)`

Comment: Yeah, raise NotImplementedError and catch in another place, then show the message box